# Como hacer que el navbar se coma el contenido?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, mediaqueries

Tengo el siguiente problema. Hice un `navbar` con `html` y `css`, tengo también un `main` con 3 imágenes con `grids`, sobre estas imágenes tengo un texto el cual tiene `Position:absolute` para quedar sobre las imágenes.

El problema viene cuando empiezo a bajar en la pagina, este texto se muestra por sobre el `navbar` y no puedo solucionarlo. Intenté cambiándole el position al `navbar` pero nunca funciona. Si cambio el `position` al texto, este se pone a un lado.

No puedo encontrar la solución, desde ya muchas gracias!

Este es mi código `html`.

```html
<header>
  <!-- inicia  navbar -->
  <div class="header__superior">
    <div class="logo1">
      <img src="img/Logofreda.png" alt="LOGO" />
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Que buscas?" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__menu">
    <div class="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check__menu" />
      <label id="label__check" for="check__menu">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars icon__menu"></i>
          </label>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Imagenes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre Mi</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- fin  navbar -->
</header>

<!-- inicia main con imagenes -->

<main>
  <p class="mensaje" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
    BIENVENIDO A MUNDOFREDA
  </p>
  <p class="mensaje2" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
    En esta pagina vas a encontrar los mejores productos para tus amigos felinos.
    <br /> Desde servicios de paseos, hasta juguetes, alimentos, baños y mucho mas!
  </p>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="img1 img"></div>
    <div class="img2 img"></div>
    <div class="img3 img"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: una imagen del problema]

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Intenta ponerle un `z-index: 1000;` por ejemplo a `header__superior` y nos cuentas cómo te va.

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta, pero lo intente y no funciona :(

Comment: Agrega entonces el `CSS` a la pregunta para revisar que puede estar sucediendo. Sin ello va a ser imposible ayudarte. Te recomiendo hacer el tour para que conozcas las normas de la comunidad. Está acá abajo, en el menú del footer.